# Is it possible to configure a Raspberry Pi 3 to become a Bluetooth adapter for a desktop PC?

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+, bluetooth

Stupid question, but I've been looking everywhere. I want to configure my Raspberry Pi 3 so that it can basically serve as a bluetooth adapter for my desktop pc. Is this possible, or does it only work for Wi-Fi connections and such?

Comment: It is possible for the Pi to pair with bluetooth devices, but act as an adapter for a PC? I'm sure it's *possible*, but it's probably way more work than it's worth to just buying a $5 USB adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use an RPi3 in that way. The RPi3 doesn't support USB OTG. Use a RPi Zero W.

Comment: So, if I were to use a Pi Zero W instead of a Pi 3 (since it apparently doesn't work), could it serve as a Bluetooth adapter in that case?

Comment: There's various modes a Zero can be used as a USB device. https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41